# Variable passed through environment not available in script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to write an if/elif/else statement where if a variable equals "Full" it will cat a file and if the same variable equals "Quick" it will read a different, smaller file. The variable is being set outside of the script and is being exported by `export var1=Quick`

I have

```
#!/bin/sh
echo $var1
export $var1=var1
{
#try cat-ing the file. If it cannot be read, exit with error. 
if [ "$var1" = "Full" ];
then 
echo "Full read chosen"
cat foo
exit 0
elif [ "$var1" = "Quick" ];
then
echo "Quick read chosen"
cat bar
exit 0
else
echo "Please choose quick or full"
exit 1
fi
}
```

When I try to run the script by calling `./test`, it doesn't seem like the variable is being set

```
+ '[' '' = Full ']'
+ '[' '' = Quick ']'
+ echo 'Please choose quick or full'
Please choose quick or full
+ exit 1
```

Is there a reason why, even though the variable is exported outside of the script, the variable isn't being passed to the script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following absolutely does work:

```
$ export var1=Quick
$ ./yourscript
```

...where `yourscript` is the script in question.

As such, your question needs to be adjusted to contain enough information and details to reproduce the problem.

---

As an aside, your script would be better written thusly:

```
#!/bin/sh
case $var1 in
  Full)
    echo "Full read chosen" >&2
    cat foo
    ;;
  Quick)
    echo "Quick read chosen" >&2
    cat bar
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Please choose quick or full" >&2
    exit 1
    ;;
esac
exit 0
```

Both of the following work for me:

```
$ var1=Quick ./yourscript
Quick read chosen
cat: bar: No such file or directory
$ (export var1=Quick; ./yourscript)
Quick read chosen
cat: bar: No such file or directory
```

Comment: I'm going to mark this as solved using your answer. I have to give you major kudos for your patience with me. I think anything wrong with the script thus far has been weirdness on my end. Deleting the test file and re-creating it allowed the script to work. Must have been something weird I wasn't seeing.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the name of your variable. Change $var1 to $1 will do the trick.

Comment: Actually, the OP is passing the variable via an export, not on the command line.  His script works for me as it is.

Comment: I couldn't get mine working doing the export. I'm still curious why that doesn't work for me

Comment: @NukaRaku, could you show the exact sequence of commands by which this fails in your question (that is, exactly where/how you're running the `export` before running your script)? Passing variables via the environment absolutely *can* be made to work (given which, I actually consider this answer incorrect, as it states that the approach you're attempting is inherently broken).

Comment: Sure, first I run `export var1=Quick`, then I call the script ./testscript. Then it fails stating "Please choose quick or full". That's really it. Nothing more to it. In fact, I just tested it again and, unless I run exactly how the answer states it, it will fail for me. I'm not looking to pass the variable directly. An export should be sufficient.

Comment: In fact, here is the direct output. To troubleshoot, I added an echo in the script
`+ echo

+ export var1=
+ var1=
+ echo

+ '[' '' = Full ']'
+ '[' '' = Quick ']'
+ echo 'Please choose quick or full'
Please choose quick or full
+ exit 1`

Comment: You're running `export var1=` inside your script? Of course it's being set to an empty value, then. Also, you didn't do that inside what you posted in your question, meaning your real script and your question differed materially.

Comment: I'm not running export in my script. I put that there to see if that would help solve my issue. You had asked why the export showed in the `set -x`. That was why.